# Windows Installer Custom Action dll TargetPath?

Tags: windows-installer

I've created a custom action dll (vb.net) to execute a file that's installed along with my project.

How do I provide the target path to the dll? As this can be changed during the installer I cannot hard code the path within the DLL?

If this is not possible could I put the file in a temp location and execute from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the setup authoring tool you are using, an MSI package supports this type of custom actions:

- [win32 DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx)
- [.NET Installer Class](http://devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx)
- standard DLL
- any EXE file

So you should first make sure that your custom action is supported by Windows Installer.

After you have a working custom action, you can pass the file path to it through a [file reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For example:

```
[#myFileId.ext]
```

Where "myFileId.ext" is the file ID from [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table.

This reference can be saved in [CustomActionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28VS.80%29.aspx) which is read by your DLL custom action or passed as a command line argument to an EXE custom action.